# Viewing epub content with html pages and graphics in Java

Tags: java, epub

I built a simple ebook reader with Java. The application reads an epub, extract it in memory (with java.util.zip.ZipFile) and hold the html pages in "internal" objects (Strings). That works very good.
But in that way I only get the text-only content of the chapters. Is there a workaround with which I also get the corresponding css or jpgs?
The problem is that the html pages use of course tags like these:

```
<img src="images/example.jpg"/>
<link stylesheet="text/css" href="styles/example.css"/>
```

From my internal objects I want to put the content to a webview but after filtering, removing some information etc. That's why I don't want to extract the epub to a temporary folder and try to keep all in memory.

Comment: Java has a built-in web browser that can probably do this for you...

Comment: You know that you can modify something in memory and then write it to that temporary folder, right?

Comment: Yes but the thing is that I don't want to store files physically.